# Getting the same error again and again [Error: A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred]

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am getting same problem again and again for last 10 days. I am using React Native CLI and trying to achieve Social Logins through Firebase.

Here's my main app.js file

```
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';


export default function App() {
  GoogleSignin.configure({
    webClientId: '22141653705-prn44vqplfc5gnnvta1agv60mqb59tht.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  });
  const signInWithGoogleAsync = async () => {
// Get the users ID token
      try{
        const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

      // Create a Google credential with the token
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);

      // Sign-in the user with the credential
      const user_sign_in = auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
      
      user_sign_in.then((user) => {
        console.log(user);
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      })
      }
      catch(error){
        console.log(error);

      }
  }
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
      <Button title="Sign in with Google" onPress={signInWithGoogleAsync} />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Here's my google-services.json file

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "22141653705",
    "project_id": "rn-firebase-c65e0",
    "storage_bucket": "rn-firebase-c65e0.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:22141653705:android:412f6758b9a9e4c400b318",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.testfirebase"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "22141653705-jmmnfqj5g1vsjd10b3aneobfqopcdas0.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "com.testfirebase",
            "certificate_hash": "203e8b51da549d3be63bb70183478696cda25b5f"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "22141653705-prn44vqplfc5gnnvta1agv60mqb59tht.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyD2pTmhBUQA4ZtT6WEBuG88wAdnmY8Mw1Q"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "22141653705-prn44vqplfc5gnnvta1agv60mqb59tht.apps.googleusercontent.com",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Here are my screenshots for SHA keys and other configurations:
[SHA 1 keys of debug Android Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2HIr.png)

[WebClientId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdJJh.png)

[SHA Fingerprints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls0Ma.png)

Comment: Hi there! Do you have any stack traces to share from (for instance) `adb logcat` as this error happens? What versions of the software are in use, and how exactly to you reproduce the error? You might like to see a complete example of react-native-firebase with social auth, demonstrated here for people to see one path towards success: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-authentication-example/

Comment: The adb logcat gave me a long list of errors. Not share what to send you from that long list. To reproduce this error I am using @react-native-firebase/auth and @react-native-google-signin. I have tried this in almost every pixel device I had in my Android Studio emulator.

Comment: "Not share what to send you from that long list" this should be rewritten as "I've investigated them using web search to filter down to the ones that seem related, and (I think, in your case based on a discord conversation) I got a 12500 error which indicates my project is not configured with a support email address" or similar. If you don't provide actual information and try hard yourself to push it forward, progress is not possible